# How do I apply a nix-shell config in a docker image?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, nix

I’m trying to use Nix as a way of unifying my local development environment and the docker based Gitlab CI build that I’m using.

I have a simple shell.nix that works perfectly - I can run nix-shell locally and get everything I need.

If, in my CI config I then use `nixos/nix:latest` as my docker image, and surround every command with `nix-shell --run "xxx"` that all works. That `nix-shell` all over the place is tedious to maintain and hard to read what is actually going on. What I'd like to do is apply that configuration to the docker image somehow as the first command, so that the environment is available to all the subsequent build commands.

I think what I want is something like `nix-env -f shell.nix -i` but that fails with “This derivation is not meant to be built, aborting”.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `buildEnv` to combine your tools into a single derivation.

**default.nix**:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

pkgs.buildEnv {
  name = "my-tools";
  paths = [
    pkgs.hello
    pkgs.figlet
  ];
}
```

Now you can install your tools in the docker image:

```
nix-env -i -f default.nix
```

And use it in your **shell.nix**:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

pkgs.mkShell {
  name = "shell-dummy";
  buildInputs = [ (import ./default.nix { inherit pkgs; }) ];
}
```

See also the [Declarative Package Management](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/index.html#sec-declarative-package-management) section in the Nixpkgs manual.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I hadn't quite understood what `buildEnv` was for so that is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is the magic command:

```
nix-env -f shell.nix -i -A buildInputs
```

This uses the `buildInputs` list in `mkShell` as a list of derivations to install into the environment. This is simpler, but represents a less clean separation of concerns than Robert's answer.

Comment: This will install them as separate packages, whereas my solution installs a single "my-tools" package with everything in it. This matters for `nix-env -q`, `nix-env -e`. What's best depends on your use case. For a docker image it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes, I realised that and that's why yours is the accepted answer!